# Unified method to parse string in any ISO-8601 compliant format

Tags: java, datetime, timezone, jodatime, fasterxml

I need a unified method to parse any [ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) compliant string. Unfortunately, neither Joda nor fastxml StdDateFormat is fully qualified to do that.

I want interpret the following two attributes

- String start;
- String timezone;

`start` is a ISO-8601 compliant string, could be in any compliant format, e.g "2020-05-15T20:30:52+03:00" or 2020-05-15". `timezone` is [IANA timezone](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/timezones.html), e.g. "Europe/Moscow".

The desired logic is:

1. If `timezone` if not specified, extend `start` to fully qualified UTC regardless of what timezone info it includes. For example, extend "2020-05-15T20:30" to "2020-05-15T20:30:00.000Z".
2. If `timezone` is specified, and timezone info in `start` conflicts with `timezone`, then report error. For example, `timezone` = "Asia/Shanghai" and `start` = "2020-05-15T20:30:52+03:00".
3. If `timezone` is specified, and has no conflict with timezone info in `start`, then extend `start` to fully qualified ISO-8601 format. For example, `timezone` = "Europe/Moscow", `start` = "2020-05-15T20:30+03:00", then extend `start` to "2020-05-15T20:30:00.000+03:00".
4. If `timezone` is specified, and `start` has no timezone info, then add `timezone` to `start` and extend it to fully qualified ISO-8601 format. For example, `timezone` = "Europe/Moscow" and `start` = "2020-05-15", then extend `start` to "2020-05-15T00:00:00.000+03:00".

This code snippet focuses on parsing ISO-8601 compliant strings. No `timezone` parameter is involve yet. It tries with `Joda DateTime` and `fasterxml StdDateFormat`.

```java
import java.util.Date;

import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.DateTimeZone;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.StdDateFormat;

public class ISOTest2 {

    public void test() {

        String [] inputs = new String [] {
                "2019-06-16T09:30:20+06:00",
                "2019-06-16T09:30Z",
                "2019-06-16T09:30:20",
                "2019-06-16T09:30",
                "2019-06-16T",
                "2019-06-16",
                "20190616T09:30:20+06:00",
                "20190618T110044Z"
        };

        StdDateFormat df = new StdDateFormat();

        for (String input : inputs) {

            System.out.println();

            DateTime output = null;

            boolean isStdDateFormatFail = false;

            try {
                Date date = df.parse(input);
                output = new DateTime(date);
                System.out.println("Valid for StdDateFormat:\t\t" + input);
                print(input, output);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                isStdDateFormatFail = true;
                System.out.println("=============");
                System.out.println("Invalid for StdDateFormat:\t\t" + input);
            }

            if (isStdDateFormatFail) {
                try {
                    output = DateTime.parse(input);
                    System.out.println("Valid for Joda:\t\t" + input);
                    print(input, output);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("=============");
                    System.out.println("Invalid for Joda:\t\t" + input);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void print(String input, DateTime output) {

        System.out.println("=============");
        System.out.println("Input:\t\t" + input);
        System.out.println("Output:\t\t" + output);

        DateTimeZone zone = output.getZone();
        System.out.println("Zone:\t\t" + zone);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ISOTest2 test = new ISOTest2();
        test.test();
    }
}
```

***Note** My local timezone is "Asia/Shanghai", i.e. +08:00*

#### Expected result

```
=============
Input:      2019-06-16T09:30:20+06:00
Output:     2019-06-16T09:30:20.000+06:00
Zone:       +0600

=============
Input:      2019-06-16T09:30Z
Output:     2019-06-16T09:30:00.000Z
Zone:       UTC

=============
Input:      2019-06-16T09:30:20
Output:     2019-06-16T09:30:20.000Z
Zone:       UTC

=============
Input:      2019-06-16T09:30
Output:     2019-06-16T09:30:00.000Z
Zone:       UTC

=============
Input:      2019-06-16T
Output:     2019-06-16T00:00:00.000Z
Zone:       UTC

=============
Input:      2019-06-16
Output:     2019-06-16T00:00:00.000Z
Zone:       UTC

=============
Input:      20190616T09:30:20+06:00
Output:     2019-06-16T09:30:20.000+06:00
Zone:       +0600

=============
Input:      20190618T110044Z
Output:     2019-06-18T11:00:44.000Z
Zone:       UTC
```

#### Actual result

```
Valid for StdDateFormat:        2019-06-16T09:30:20+06:00
=============
Input:      2019-06-16T09:30:20+06:00
Output:     2019-06-16T11:30:20.000+08:00
Zone:       Asia/Shanghai

Valid for StdDateFormat:        2019-06-16T09:30Z
=============
Input:      2019-06-16T09:30Z
Output:     2019-06-16T17:30:00.000+08:00
Zone:       Asia/Shanghai

Valid for StdDateFormat:        2019-06-16T09:30:20
=============
Input:      2019-06-16T09:30:20
Output:     2019-06-16T17:30:20.000+08:00
Zone:       Asia/Shanghai

Valid for StdDateFormat:        2019-06-16T09:30
=============
Input:      2019-06-16T09:30
Output:     2019-06-16T17:30:00.000+08:00
Zone:       Asia/Shanghai

=============
Invalid for StdDateFormat:      2019-06-16T
Valid for Joda:     2019-06-16T
=============
Input:      2019-06-16T
Output:     2019-06-16T00:00:00.000+08:00
Zone:       Asia/Shanghai

Valid for StdDateFormat:        2019-06-16
=============
Input:      2019-06-16
Output:     2019-06-16T08:00:00.000+08:00
Zone:       Asia/Shanghai

=============
Invalid for StdDateFormat:      20190616T09:30:20+06:00
Valid for Joda:     20190616T09:30:20+06:00
=============
Input:      20190616T09:30:20+06:00
Output:     20190616-01-01T09:30:20.000+06:00
Zone:       +06:00

=============
Invalid for StdDateFormat:      20190618T110044Z
=============
Invalid for Joda:       20190618T110044Z
```

#### Blocking issues

There are three blocking issues.

1. `fasterxml StdDateFormat` will change `original timezone` to `local timezone` implicitly. For example, input string is "2019-06-16T09:30:20+06:00", output Date is "2019-06-16T11:30:20.000+08:00".
2. When no timezone info is included in `start`, both `Joda` and `fasterxml` adds local timezone implicitly. For example, input string is "2019-06-16T09:30", output Date is "2019-06-16T17:30:00.000+08:00". (My local timezone is "Asia/Shanghai", e.g. +08:00) What I'm expecting is a chance to add `timezone` to it. For example, there's another parameter specified to be "Asia/Shanghai", `start` = "2019-06-16T09:30", the desired output is something like: "2019-06-16T09:30" + "Asia/Shanghai" = "2019-06-16T09:30:00.000+08:00".
3. `fasterxml` cannot parse "20190616T09:30:20+06:00". Neither Joda nor fastermxl can parse "20190618T110044Z".

Comment: You have not even covered all possible ISO variants, for example: `2019-W01-7T03:59Z`.

Comment: No, I haven't. But even the incomplete list of variants cannot be properly handled.